# create user in keycloak 4.8.3 programmatically with java

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I want to create a user through keycloak admin client but I am  getting:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: 
>           javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request

Heading I expect returning the user created successfully but it generate 400 bad request error

```
String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8180/auth";
String realm = "demo";
String clientId = "idm-client";
String clientSecret = "a200cdf6-ad72-4f6c-af73-5b8e1cc48876";

Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder() 
    .serverUrl(serverUrl) //
    .realm(realm) //
    .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS) //
    .clientId(clientId) //
    .clientSecret(clientSecret).build();

// Define user
UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
user.setEnabled(true);
user.setUsername("tester1");
user.setFirstName("First");
user.setLastName("Last");
user.setEmail("tom+tester1@tdlabs.local");
user.setAttributes(Collections.singletonMap("origin", 
Arrays.asList("demo")));

// Get realm
RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm(realm);
UsersResource userRessource = realmResource.users();

// Create user (requires manage-users role)
Response response = userRessource.create(user);
System.out.println("Repsonse: " + response.getStatusInfo());
```

The line that  generate the error is:

```
Response response = userRessource.create(user);
```

Comment: I guess that one is the app log. Do you get anything in the Keycloak server logs?

Comment: no i get anything

Answer (score 2):

You can create a user if you change your code from:

```
String clientId = "idm-client";
String clientSecret = "a200cdf6-ad72-4f6c-af73-5b8e1cc48876";

Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder() 
    .serverUrl(serverUrl) //
    .realm(realm) //
    .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS) //
    .clientId(clientId) //
    .clientSecret(clientSecret).build();
```

to:

```
Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(
    serverUrl,
    "master",
    "admin", // Change to your admin name
    "password", // Change to your admin password
    "admin-cli");
```

See also:
[Keycloak Server Developer Guide - 2.2. Example using Java](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_development/index.html#example-using-java)

**EDIT**

You can find out the reason why BadRequestException occurs if you add the following method

```java
private static void handleClientErrorException(ClientErrorException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Response response = e.getResponse();
    try {
        System.out.println("status: " + response.getStatus());
        System.out.println("reason: " + response.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase());
        Map error = JsonSerialization.readValue((ByteArrayInputStream) response.getEntity(), Map.class);
        System.out.println("error: " + error.get("error"));
        System.out.println("error_description: " + error.get("error_description"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and surround the try-catch block:

```java
try {
    Response response = userRessource.create(user);
} catch (ClientErrorException e) {
    handleClientErrorException(e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    if (cause instanceof ClientErrorException) {
        handleClientErrorException((ClientErrorException) cause);
    } else {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but  i need to obtain instance of keyclok by the realm that i have created